# How to make a custom manager work with non-default database in django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-1.5, django-managers

I want to make a custom manager for my models stored in my database 'db2' so that i don't have to do `model.objects.using('db2').all()`.
The code for my models and custom manager is

```
class ViewerProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
    return super(ViewerProfileManager,self).using('db2').get_query_set() # results in recursion error

class ViewerProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    count = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)

    objects = models.Manager()
    profiles = ViewerProfileManager()
-------------

>>> ViewerProfile.profiles.all() # maximum recursion depth exceeded error
```

What's wrong with what i am doing here and how to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION** : If you just want to use another database 'db2' for every query just use this

```
class ViewerProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    count = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)

    objects = models.Manager()
    profiles = objects.db_manager('db2')    # manager for evaluating querysets on database db2
```

Later on if you want to add custom querysets override objects manager by making a class inheriting from models.Manager and define your querysets in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the method on the parent (using `super()`) or do the appropriate handling of the `_db` attribute on the manager (a string containing the name of the database to use).
If you want to return a custom `QuerySet` class from the `get_query_set` method :

```py
class ViewerProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        qs = CustomQuerySet(self.model)
        if self._db is not None:
            qs = qs.using(self._db)
        return qs
```

or use this:

```py
class ViewerProfileManager(models.Manager):
    using="db"
    def get_query_set(self,request):
        return super(ViewerProfileManager,self).queryset(request).using(self.using)

class ViewerProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    count = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)

    objects = models.Manager()
    profiles = ViewerProfileManager()
```

`self._db` is going to be affected by the name of your database.

Comment: where do you specify this _db value?

Comment: you have to specified it self._db="db_name"

Comment: you can use the first method or another.